# Game Center Leadboards not Showing and In Apps not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, game-center

I have been developing a client game. I have enabled game center from iTunesConnect, created leaderboards and also created InApps. But when I try to call them in the code, there is no response. Game Center is showing no items and in apps are giving any response i.e products are not loaded. Everything is correct, provisioning is correct, bundle id is setup correctly, game center and in apps are enabled. I tried the same code with my own game center and in apps and they worked fine. One thing missing in client's itunes connect is Contact and Tax Information. Is that the problem? Thats why apple isnt allowing me to add game center and in apps? Thanks